# Euler’s gamma functions and exponential integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, trigonometric-integrals, branch-cuts

I am trying to solve these integrals,[image] 
where $ (C_i,S_i) ≡ (\cos λp_i, \sin λp_i)$
I have done $D_{SS}$. But in $D_{SC}$, I encounter some divergences.
The author says this in the paper:

> The integration of λ in Eqs. (C15)-(C18) seems straightforward as one can express the trigonometric
> functions to exponential functions and then convert the integrals to Euler’s gamma functions. It
> is worth mentioning, however, that one should handle the branch cut singularities in the gamma
> functions carefully

Could any of you point me to some resources regarding solving these types of integrals? Where can I read up on exponential integrals and gamma functions?
Apologies if this is not the right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to follow the process described in your quotation, you will want

- the [exponential forms of sine and cosine](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.14) (alternatively, (3) [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cosine.html) and (4) [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sine.html), or [alt. ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Relationship_to_exponential_function_(Euler%27s_formula)))
- [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) (probably, although one might sneak around this requirement), and
- the [gamma function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2), et seq. ([alt. ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), [alt. ref.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html))

For instance, using the exponential forms of sine and cosine in the integrand of $D_{SC}$, we obtain
$$ D_{SC} = \frac{4}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{-1}{16 \lambda^2} \left( \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}p_1 \lambda} - \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}p_1 \lambda} \right)  
\left( \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}p_2 \lambda} - \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}p_2 \lambda} \right)
\left( \left( \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}p_3 \lambda} + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}p_3 \lambda} \right) - \frac{\mathrm{i}\left( \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}p_3 \lambda} - \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}p_3 \lambda} \right)}{p_3 \lambda} \right)
\left( \left( \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}p_4 \lambda} + \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}p_4 \lambda} \right) - \frac{\mathrm{i}\left( \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}p_4 \lambda} - \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}p_4 \lambda} \right)}{p_4 \lambda} \right) \,\mathrm{d}\lambda
$$

The remainder of this process is a herculean effort.  Are you sure you wouldn't be happier evaluating these integrals using the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Using_the_Cauchy_integral_formula)?

Comment: Sound good! But I have to read up on Cauchy integral formula. Can you briefly say how do I take contours for Cauchy integral? since this has a pole at $z=0$, I am not sure. If you could elaborate a little on how to do Cauchy integral for $D_{SS}$ it would be really helpful :) I will extrapolate from there for others.

Comment: @annoying_noob : The singularity at zero is removable for all of these.  The integrand in $D_{SS}$ is $p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 \lambda^2 + O(\lambda^4)$, in $D_{SC}$ and $D_{CS}$ is $(1/9)p_1 p_2 p_3^2 p_4^2 \lambda^4 + O(\lambda^6)$, and in $D_{CC}$ is $(1/81) p_1^2 p_2^2 p_3^2 p_4^2 \lambda^6 + O(\lambda^8)$.  So the contour integral on the boundary of the (upper) half disk of radius $R$ is zero -- meaning the straight and curved parts give the same magnitude and opposite signs.  (cont.)

Comment: @annoying_noob : Also, these integrands are even in $\lambda$, so $\int_0^\infty = (1/2)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = (1/2)$ the straight part of the contour as $R \rightarrow \infty$.